# string concat on datetime index

Tags: python, pandas

Very simple question but somehow I cannot find the answer. Lets say we have a pandas dataframe with a datetime as index.

why does this:

```
dfc["ident_key"] = str(dfc.index.quarter) + "_" + str(dfc.index.month) + "_" + str(dfc.index.hour)
```

Not turn into a string of the format:

```
q_m_h
```

But rather into:

Int64Index([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,\n ...

How do I get to the desired results for instance for today 13:00 it should return a string 3_7_13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass it to dataframe

```
pd.DataFrame([df.index.quarter , df.index.month , df.index.hour]).astype(str).agg('_'.join)
```

Or use `astype`

```
df.index.quarter.astype(str)+ "_" + df.index.month.astype(str)+ "_" + df.index.hour.astype(str)
```

Comment: I really like the first one but it doesnt work or at least it would require reindexing on the dataframe to get it into the original frame. Also, my df is large and first one is VERY slow. The astype worked nicely

Answer (score 1):

You are calling an index object rather than its values.

In your case:

```
dfc.index.quarter.values
```

will return a numpy array of quarter values, same with other datetime parts. Then you can process them as you like.

Comment: somehow this seems to return the entire array in each row, I obviously only want the value for the index in that row entry

Comment: This is because you are not casting individual elements as strings but rather a whole array as a string. The result of your operation is one string, not an array of strings, therefore when you assign it to a column it just fills all the rows with the same string. You need to cast the array using `.astype(str)`, not `str()` operator on the whole array.